# Some point set topology regarding the set $[7, \infty)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Consider the set $A=[7, \infty)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
a) Determine $\operatorname{int}A$, $\operatorname{cl} A$, $A'$ and $\delta A$.
b) Is $A$ connected or compact?
Ok, so for a) I think that $\operatorname{int}A=(7, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, $\operatorname{cl} A=[7, \infty)$, $A'=[7, \infty)$, $\delta A=\operatorname{cl}A\setminus \operatorname{int}A=[7, \infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.
For b), $A$ is not connected because it is not an interval and it is not compact because it is not bounded.
I would like to know if I am right because I have just started learning general topology.

Comment: What is the definition of $A'$?

Comment: @Klaus the derived set.

Comment: How is $5\pi$ (say) an internal point of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure and $A'$ are correct, but the interior is empty (!): all open sets in $\Bbb R$ contain rationals, so no non-empty open set can be contained in $A$ which consists only of *irrational* numbers.

So $\delta A= \text{cl} A$.

$A$ is indeed not connected (it's not order convex, is the more technical property you mean). E.g. we can separate it on any rational $>7$, $A = (A \cap (-\infty,8)) \cup (A \cap (8, \infty))$ e.g.

The unboundedness *and* non-closedness of $A$ both show non-compactness of $A$.

Comment: oh, right, I made such a foolish mistake, of course that the interior is the empty set ! Regarding the non-compactness, correct me if I am wrong, but since a set $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact $\iff$ it is closed and bounded, wouldn't it have been enough to say that $A$ is unbounded?

Comment: @JustAnAmateur Or you could say that it is not closed as well. So *both* are valid reasons on their own. That's what my final sentence means to say.